# Disable 'remember password' prompt from javascript or code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need to disable "Remember Password" prompt coming in browser, either through code behind or from javascript. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can add "autocomplete = off" to your inputs.

```
<input ... autocomplete="off" />
```

OR

```
document.getElementById('password').setAttribute( 'autocomplete', 'off' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `autocomplete` to `off` to inputs

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off" />
    <input type="password" name="username" autocomplete="off" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this both on form level and specific field level.

**Form Level:**

You can set the autocomplete to off. By using JQuery you can do like this

```
$('#form').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
```

or in html5. You can use autocomplete attribute. like

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" autocomplete="off">
```

**Specific Fields**

or for specific fields  you can do this

```
<input type="text" name="password" autocomplete="off" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property of your form..

```
autocomplete="off"
```

so that you can avoid remembering Username and Password fields...

Please Mark as answer if it satisfies you..